# Android 4.0. SearchView: Icon not show on the right side

Tags: android, searchview

In my `Fragment` I has `SearchView` in `ConstraintLayout`.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_bg"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:searchHintIcon="@null" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how I set icon on the right border

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(view.findViewById(R.id.searchView), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Here's the result:

[image: Correct]

OK. It's work on **Android 4.3+**

But if I start on **Android 4.0** then I get the next result:

[image: Wrong]

As you can see the icon is not show on the right side.

How move icon to the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the gravity to layout params.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) searchview.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
searchView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: my SearchView is not in Menu. It's in fragment

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: Cast it to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to avoid the exception.

Comment: `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) searchView.getLayoutParams();`   But I get compile error: `params.gravity = Gravity.END;`

Comment: You have to take the layout params from the `SearchView`, not from the `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: `SearchView.LayoutParams params = (SearchView.LayoutParams) searchView.getLayoutParams();
        params.gravity = Gravity.END;
        searchView.setLayoutParams(params);` - again error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat$LayoutParams`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156581/discussion-between-reaz-murshed-and-alex).